# Mod_Rewrite dynamic page and redirect

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm creating a dynamic page with a url e.g.:

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/stocklist/item.php?id=int&name=string

is there a way that i can combine a url rewrite with a redirect to point all dynamic links to:

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/stocklist/id/name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# add this following cond if the Rewrite rule rewrites css, js etc. files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^stocklist/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ stocklist/item.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: its throwing up a 404 error. should this be stored in the /stocklist folder or root?

Comment: It will be on root. Remove the RewriteCond.

Comment: Thanks. the rewrite is working perfectly. i adapted it a little to:

    RewriteRule ^stocklist/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ stocklist/animal.php?id=$1&name=$2[NC,L]

But now ive got the issue that all the relative paths to resources like stylesheets, are lost. Do you know how to sort this too :)?

Comment: @AndyKing I have updated answer to prevent problem with css, js files